# toLocaleString shows '0' at the end when length exceeds

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6, numbers

I am using toLocaleString but it keeps on adding after certain length

```
 let integer = 46738399923867126778;
   
        const integerPart = (integer).toLocaleString('en-IN',{maximumSignificantDigits:21});
        console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(integer));

        console.log(integerPart);
```

output :

- 4,67,38,39,99,23,86,71,20,000
- 4,67,38,39,99,23,86,71,20,000

I want it to show the number provided with the formatting specfied and not add zeroes

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: The problem isn't with `toLocaleString`. It's that the `integer` number value doesn't have that many decimal digits in the first place. Use a bigint if you need the precision.